# Getting error while running mvn clean install in hygieia/API

Tags: java, maven, hygiene

While running `mvn clean install` in hygieia/API

```
[ERROR] Errors: [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_DIRECT:122->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_HTTP:78->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_HTTP_lowercase:100->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_SOCKS:144->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_empty:175->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_null:219->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] MonitorProxyConfigTest.testProxy_PROXY_whitespace:197->assertAuthenticator:370 » InaccessibleObject Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.Authenticator java.net.Authenticator.theAuthenticator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7bfcd12c [ERROR] ServiceServiceTest.update:93 » NullPointer
```

After running `mvn clean install` in hygieia API folder I need to get API.jar file but it is showing error.